# Is there a benefit to "increased Block and Stun Recovery" when you can't be stunned?

Tags: path-of-exile

I play sword and board so I block attacks all the time.
As I understand it [blocking includes a short block animation](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Blocking).
And "If you cannot be stunned, the block animation will never play"
That suggests to me that if you cannot be stunned there's no benefit to increased Block (and Stun) Recovery, is that correct?

If that's the case, it surprises me that "Unwavering Stance" and "Stun Mastery" are so close to each other. Meaning that if you take the first, the 50% increased Block and Stun Recovery granted by the second is wasted.

This might be fine, because Stun Mastery is still a good passive, can someone confirm this?

Comment: It's worth noting that positioning on the passive tree isn't a useful measure - Resolute Technique (never crit) is right next to a crit circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, stun/block recovery would provide no benefit. You could think about "cannot be stunned" as simply setting your stun/block recovery time to 0. Increasing recovery by 50% is still going to be 0.

I don't play melee builds so I can't be sure but I don't think anyone really takes stun based nodes. You are better off with more damage to stun more often, or more defense to be stunned less often.